# Improving Pandas iteration performance

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I've got the following code that takes historical prices for a single asset and calculated forecasts, and computes how you would have faired if you had really invested your money according to the forecast. In financial parlance, it's a back-test.

The main problem is that its *very* slow, and I'm not sure what the right strategy is for improving it. I need to run this thousands of times, so an order of magnitude speedup is required.

Where should I begin looking?

```
class accountCurve():
    def __init__(self, forecasts, prices):

        self.curve = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Capital','Holding','Cash','Trade', 'Position'], dtype=float)
        forecasts.dropna(inplace=True)
        self.curve['Forecast'] = forecasts
        self.curve['Price'] = prices
        self.curve.loc[self.curve.index[0],['Capital', 'Holding', 'Cash', 'Trade', 'Position']] = [10000, 0, 10000, 0, 0]

        for date, forecast in forecasts.iteritems():
            x=self.curve.loc[date]
            previous = self.curve.shift(1).loc[date]
            if previous.isnull()['Cash']==False:
                x['Cash'] = previous['Cash'] - previous['Trade'] * x['Price']
                x['Position'] = previous['Position'] + previous['Trade']

            x['Holding'] = x['Position'] * x['Price']
            x['Capital'] = x['Cash'] + x['Holding']
            x['Trade'] = np.fix(x['Capital']/x['Price'] * x['Forecast']/20) - x['Position']
```

Edit:

Datasets as requested:

Prices:

```
import quandl
corn = quandl.get('CHRIS/CME_C2')
prices = corn['Open']
```

Forecasts:

```
def ewmac(d):
    columns = pd.Series([2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64])
    g = lambda x: d.ewm(span = x, min_periods = x*4).mean() - d.ewm(span = x*4, min_periods=x*4).mean()
    f = columns.apply(g).transpose()
    f = f*10/f.abs().mean()
    f.columns = columns
    return f.clip(-20,20)
forecasts=ewmac(prices)
```

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so one could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to achieve in your `for date, forecast in forecasts.iteritems()` loop? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you do df.head() for your inputs and, so people can see the structure without installing a third party library.

As an aside, itertuples is quicker, as iteritems and iterrows have to construct a series object for each iteration.

Comment: I think you might have to use numba for something like this, though it's hard to be sure with the question as it currently stands.  I suggest renaming all you columns to single letters a-g and presenting a few rows of sample input and output. Also, if I've read it correctly, when `x['Cash']` is `nan`/`null`, all the other things become `nan` too, which is to say they aren't modified from their defaults, so you could have skipped the iteration completely..so use `dropna` more effectively outside the loop...indeed you should loop over `curve` itself rather than `forecasts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a numpy array instead of a data frame inside the `for` loop. It usually gives significant speed boost.

So the code may look like:

```
class accountCurve():
    def __init__(self, forecasts, prices):
        self.curve = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Capital','Holding','Cash','Trade', 'Position'], dtype=float)
        # forecasts.dropna(inplace=True)
        self.curve['Forecast'] = forecasts.dropna()
        self.curve['Price'] = prices
        # helper np.array:
        self.arr = np.array(self.curve)
        self.arr[0,:5] = [10000, 0, 10000, 0, 0]

        for i in range(1, self.arr.shape[0]):
            this = self.arr[i]
            prev = self.arr[i-1]
            cash = prev[2] - prev[3] * this[6]
            position = ...
            holding = ...
            capital = ...
            trade = ...
            this[:5] = [capital, holding, cash, trade, position]

        # back to data frame:
        self.curve[['Capital','Holding','Cash','Trade', 'Position']] = self.arr[:,:5]
        # or maybe this would be faster:
        # self.curve[:] = self.arr
```

I don't quite understand the significance of the line `if previous.isnull()['Cash']==False:`. It looks as if `previous['Cash']` was never null, except maybe for the first row - but you set the first row earlier.

Also, you may consider executing `forecasts.dropna(inplace=True)` outside of the class. If its originally a data frame, you'll run it once instead of repeating it for every column. (Do I understand correctly that you input single columns of `forecasts` into the class?)

Next step I'd recommend is using some line profiler to see where your code spends most of the time and trying to optimize these bottlenecks. If you use ipython then you can try running `%prun` or `%lprun`. For example

```
%lprun -f accountCurve.__init__  A = accountCurve(...)
```

will produce stats for every line in your `__init__`.

Comment: That's quite a lot 'nicer' as well, at the very least it will look better! The previous.isnull() is only for the first row (though I hate to test repeatedly all the way down). Perhaps there's a cleaner way. Thanks for your help, I'll try %lprun!

Comment: @cjm2671 Glad I could help. As for `previous.isnull()` test, the cleaner way is to do what you need with the first row before the loop and run the loop starting from the second row. My code is supposed to do exactly that with `for i in range(1,...)`; but it's more complicated with `iteritems`.